# What is a good way to describe 10 paper napkins, folded together?

Tags: word-choice

What is a good way to describe 10 paper napkins, folded together?
Possibilities: "wad", "clump", "bunch"... 
None of these feels like quite the right word...
Thanks-

Comment: Do you mean to say "What is the collective noun for paper napkins"?

Comment: @Holyprogrammer No, I'm specifically asking about when they are folded together.

Comment: How about a “sheaf”?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how they are organized.  If they are one on top of the other, we would call that a "stack"

> In the early morning hours, workers placed **stacks** of folded newspapers on the loading dock, ready for delivery to newsstands and paperboys throughout the city.

If placed side-by-side you could call them a "row"

> She lined up the folded invitations in neat little **rows** on the table before her, organized alphabetically.

If jumbled together with no organization, you could call them a "heap" or a "pile" (although this implies they may no longer be neatly folded)

> As a tradition, after opening and reading them out loud, the family would always throw the holiday cards into a **heap** in the center of the living room.

Comment: I've specified their manner of organisation as being *folded together* ... They are not simply stacked or placed in rows or jumbled, they are folded into one... Wad? Clump? Bunch? Other...?

Comment: @sesquipedalias  We would just say *folded together*, although *set*, *array*, *assortment*, or *bundle* all might work in a particular context.